# Is it true that if A is not diagonal matrix and B is diagonal matrix so AB is not diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

as I mentioned: Is it true that if A is not diagonal matrix and B is diagonal matrix so AB is not diagonal?

furthermore, is it true that AB diagonal iff A is diagonal and B is diagonal?

I know this is pretty elementary knowledge in linear algebra but could't find the information in Google.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is false. If you take $B=\mathbf{0}$ equal to the zero matrix, it is diagonal and so is $AB$.

If $A,B$ are both diagonal, then the product $AB$ is certainly diagonal. This can be verified by direct computation.

The converse is false. For example, the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ is not diagonal, but the product $A^2=\mathbf{0}$ is.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is true. If $B = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ and $AB = \text{diag}(\lambda_1', \ldots, \lambda_n')$ for some basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$, this means that $B(e_i) = \lambda_ie_i$ and $AB(e_i) = \lambda_i'e_i$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$. But then
$$
\lambda_i'e_i = AB(e_i) = A(\lambda_ie_i) = \lambda_iA(e_i)
$$
so
$$
A(e_i) = \frac{\lambda_i'}{\lambda_i}e_i
$$
for $i=1, \ldots, n$. This means that $A = \text{diag}(\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_n)$ with $\mu_i = \lambda_i'/\lambda_i$.

Comment: Are you sure? I wouldn't be.

Comment: Oops right, this argument only works if $B$ is invertible!