# If $AB^{-1}A^\top$ is diagonal, then does it imply that $A$ and $B$ have to be diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For square matrices $A$ and $B$ (which is invertible), if $AB^{-1}A^\top$ is diagonal with non-zero diagonal entries, then does it imply that $A$ and $B$ have to be diagonal (the converse is obviously true)? Are there other type (e.g., triangular, orthonormal, etc.) of matrices $A$ and $B$ that would give us a diagonal $AB^{-1}A^\top$? (I thought of this question after seeing another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789493/is-it-true-that-if-a-is-not-diagonal-matrix-and-b-is-diagonal-matrix-so-ab-is-no).) The only condition is that $B$ should not be a function of $A$.

Comment: Take $A$ an orthogonal matrix which is not diagonal and $B = I$ then, $AB^{-1}A^\top = I$ is diagonal, but $A$ is not. @Lukas's answer is more general.

Comment: No, $A$ and $B$ don't have to be diagonal in that case. In fact, any normal matrix $C$ (that means $CC^{T}=C^{T}C$) is diagonalizable by an orthogonal/unitarian matrix. So if $C$ is any invertible symmetric matrix we can find a unitarian $U$ such that $UCU^T$ is diagonal. If we set $B= C^{-1}$ and $U=A$ we have exactly your situation.

Comment: Thanks. What is a unitarian matrix? More specifically, what conditions must $U$ (or $A$) fulfill? If I understood correctly, $B^{-1}$ has to be a normal matrix and $A$ has to be unitarian.

Comment: Any example with $A$ invertible and $D$ diagonal and invertible and $B= A^\top D^{-1} A$ might do, as $AB^{-1}A^\top = D$ which is diagonal

Comment: I wasn't clear in my ques but I'm looking for cases where $B$ is not a function of $A$ -- sorry, I've updated my ques.

Comment: "$B$ is not a function of $A$" is not particularly meaningful: any invertible matrix can be transformed into any another  invertible matrix of the same size by multiplication by a third matrix

Comment: If $AB^{-1}A^\top =D$ is invertible then that implies $A$ is invertible and that $B= A^\top D^{-1} A$.  It is not a question of being a function, as you have many choices for $D$

Comment: If $AB^{-1}A^T$ is diagonal, then $B$ is symmetric. Conversely, if $B$ is symmetric, then $B^{-1}$ is the matrix of a symmetric bilinear form. It is well-known that when the characteristic of the underlying field is not $2$, every symmetric bilinear form is diagonalisable by congruence. So, in this case, there exist an invertible matrix $A$ such that $AB^{-1}A^T$ is diagonal.